# How to measure iptables load?

Tags: iptables, performance, ufw

I have added about 3500 IP addresses to `iptables` using ufw on a Debian 7 and I am wondering if this has any impact on the performance of my server.

How can I measure that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of bothering with this wasteful approach why not setup an `ipset` instead. A set of IPs can be matched to a single firewall entry rather than having to maintain 3500 entries.

- [IP sets](http://ipset.netfilter.org/)

Here's a good intro/tutorial on how to use them in this Linux Journal article titled: [Advanced Firewall Configurations with ipset](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/advanced-firewall-configurations-ipset).

#### Example

Setup a set to contain your IPs.

```
$ sudo ipset -N myset iphash
$ sudo ipset -A myset 1.1.1.1
$ sudo ipset -A myset 2.2.2.2
```

Then setup the 1 `iptables` rule to make use of the set.

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --set myset src -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks! However the question remains the same. How is this impacting the performances of the server? And how can I measure it?

Comment: @momeunier - have a look at this slidedeck: http://www.slideshare.net/brouer/netfilter-making-large-iptables-rulesets-scale

Comment: Same recommendation as mine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75368/how-many-instructions-can-be-stuffed-into-iptables-without-loosing-system-sanity